# Android webview menu long press

Tags: android, menu, webview, onlongclicklistener

I have the following webview

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.setLongClickable(false);
webView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v)
    {
        return false;
    }
});

WebViewClient wvc = new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        ...
    }
};
webView.setWebViewClient(wvc);
webView.loadUrl("file://" + path);
```

As you see I have tried to block the long pressing in the webview, but when I long press the webview a menu like this one pops up:

[image: Menu popup example]

How can I disable this menu? The setLongClickable(false) and the listener doesn't seem to work

The webview is loading/showing a flash file (.swf) in full screen

Comment: Anyone having the same problem?